# How is i incremented in if-else statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, jsfiddle

Could you please explain why this code gives i = 0, 3, 6, is I increment it by 2?

```
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i+=2) {
        console.log('i = ' + i);
        if (++i == 5) break;
        else continue;
    }
    console.log(i++);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Maine/ufc1444g/6/)

Comment: `i+=2` increments `i` by 2, and `++i` increments it one more time, for a total of 3. Note that `++i ==5` will always be false in this loop since the value of `i` starts at 0, `++i` is 1 (so `i` is 1), then `i` is 3 and `++i` is 4, then `i` is 6, and `++i` is 7, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a homework question.  `++i` increments `i`, so the value of `i` is increased by three every time through the loop. Consider reading the code a bit more carefully with this type of question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with simple code as

```
for (i = 0; i < 9; i+=2) {
    console.log('i = ' + i);
    if ((i + 1) == 5) break;
    else continue;
}
console.log(++i);
```

According to your code you always add 1 in i.
In there you only check with 1.